# How do I use .SKS SKSpriteNode in GameScene?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have the player all set up with its action and everything in GameScene.swift. The thing is, I don't want it to be a still image so I removed

```
  var player: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "player1.png")
```

and I want to make it so I can use the animation SKSpriteNode I made in GameScene.sks, as the player. The SKSpriteNode in GameScene.sks is named player.

Help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

You can access items created in `GameScene.sks` in the custom class function `didMoveToView`;

```
var player: SKSpriteNode!

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    guard let player = childNode(withName: "player") as? SKSpriteNode else {
        fatalError("player node not loaded")
    }

    self.player = player
}
```

Comment: I see. I tried that. It launches, I click play and it crashes giving me an error, highlighting the fatalError line, saying "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (" and some random codes after that.

Comment: Make sure you have a node named 'player' in the `sks` file.

Comment: Also, you could read through this [article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/118225/introduction-sprite-kit-scene-editor), it has a few examples of accessing nodes in a `sks` file. It's for Swift 2, but still a good read!

Comment: I did what you said about naming it player, the error in the fatalError line but now there's some troble between it's location. that error is showing up on the line: player.position = CGPointMake(player.size.width / 2, player.size.height / 5)

Comment: What's the error message? You might not need that line because your player already has a position.

Comment: Well see, I have many funcs already set up for my player. For example, whenever you click the screen, bullets fly out of the player. The func for that contains: bullet.position = CGPointMake(player.position.x, player.position.y) which seems to be an issue. Can SKSpritenodes from .sks not have positions given by code?

Comment: Setting positions in code is Ok. You might have to post the error message.

Comment: Okay the error message when it highlights the line is: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) but the output says: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: Probably best to ask a new question with the error message and a few lines of code involved.

Comment: I agree but is there anything you can recommend? i think the reason is because I added a ? to the as in the statement he gave me on this answer. When I take away the ? it says 'sknode? is not convetible to skspritenode did you mean to use as! to force downcast?' so it might have to do with that?

Comment: The error `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` means the variables value hasn't been set, so need to understand why.

Comment: Okay. What do you mean by the var value hasn't been set? Isn't var player: SKSpriteNode! setting the value?

Comment: That is the declaration, so that the player variable can be accessed anywhere using `self.player`. Setting occurs in the example code where player is retrieved from the SKS file and is assigned with `self.player = player`